# Accessing data of nested fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make a tree of categories of up to 2 levels.
I am loading fxml dynamically in a top level controller when the user clicks on a category checkbox.

**TopLevelController.java**

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener <Boolean> () {
     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue < ? extends Boolean > ov, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
     // show resilience products
     if(newValue) {
        if(!subCategories.isEmpty()) {
            for(Category subCat : subCategories) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/SubCategory.fxml"));
                pane.getChildren().add(loader.load());
                SubCategoryController controller = loader.getController();
            }
         }
      }
    }
});
```

In some cases a child category will have other child categories so the same operation will happen in the `SubCategoryController`.

At the end of a branch in the category tree a list of items will be displayed. the user may make selections from items displayed with a checkbox/radio button to select. These selections are stored in a list List. Item is a class that holds the `Item` object and the corresponding `Control` which the user can select/check.

In `TopLevelController`there is an action related to an `Add` button. When the user clicks on this button all the user selections need to be processed. So the `TopLevelController` needs to access the List for each of the 'nested' controllers.

Can anyone suggest how this information can be passed from the 'nested' controllers to the `TopLevelController`?

Comment: Just define a method in `SubCategoryController` returning the list, and call it; you have a reference to the `SubCategoryController`. (BTW, you can simplify your code a little by removing the `if (!subCategories.isEmpty())` conditional: the `for` loop will simply not execute if the list is empty.)

Comment: @James_D But this means that if there are more levels there will be a chain of methods being called. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way. Thanks for the performance tip by the way :).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.